# Data mysteriously missing from views within same property and account

Tags: google-analytics

I've got three views set up for one profile. They were all set up several months ago, at roughly the same time. Of these three, two have data. Both of these have identical filters set up related to IP exclusions. One of these has slightly fewer hits/pagviews/etc. The third view has the identical set of filters, but no data (and has not since it was originally set up).

Has anyone experienced this before? I'm completely at a loss (again, NOT the filters) for root cause.

Thanks!

Comment: This was solved - the views with no data in them had the User ID feature enabled, but the implementation isn't capturing User ID. When the User ID feature is enabled, any hits without a User ID won't appear in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Are the filters listed in the same order for all the Views?

In the *Admin* Tab of Analytics, you can go to the *Filters* section of your Views and compare their order.

Otherwise, you could copy one of the View that has the expected data and incrementally add filters to it until it matches your intended use for it. In the *Admin* Tab, select a View's *View Settings* and click the *Copy view* button.

Comment: Yes, filters are in the same order (i.e., there's only one filter applied). I'll try the "Copy View" option and let you know...

Comment: Sure @Tom, let me know! Note that it may take up to 24 hours before for the data to process and become available in Google Analytics.